# org.openide.util.Lookup Cannot Find Any Classes Implementing

Tags: java, openide

SQLUtils.java:

```
import org.openide.util.Lookup;

import java.util.ServiceLoader; // This doesn't work either

public class SQLUtils {
    public static DBDriver getDriver(String prefix) {
        for(DBDriver e : Lookup.getDefault().lookupAll(DBDriver.class)) {
            System.out.println(e.getPrefix());
            if(e.getPrefix().equalsIgnoreCase(prefix)) {
                return e;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

MySQLDriver.java:

```
public class MySQLDriver implements DBDriver {
    @Override
    public String getPrefix() {
        return "mysql";
    }
}
```

DBDriver.java:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public interface DBDriver extends Serializable {
    public String getPrefix();
}
```

Main.java:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DBDriver d = SQLUtils.getDriver("mysql");
    }
}
```

This does nothing when running it, it cannot find any classes implementing.
What the program is trying to do is get the driver that is entered as a parameter for SQLUtils.getDriver(String prefix) (in Main.java). 
For some reason I cannot get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dropped the NetBeans API and switched to Reflections. I implemented Maven and ran it with IntelliJ. Works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with OpenIDE `Lookup` mechanism, but I am familiar with the Java `ServiceLoader` mechanism.

You need to provide a file in the `META-INF/services/` folder describing what classes implement specific interfaces. From the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) describing the `ServiceLoader` class is this example:

> If `com.example.impl.StandardCodecs` is an implementation of the
>   `com.example.CodecSet` service then its jar file also contains a file
>   named
>
> META-INF/services/com.example.CodecSet
>
> This file contains the single line:
>
> com.example.impl.StandardCodecs    # Standard codecs implementing `com.example.CodecSet`

What you are missing is a similar file that needs to be included on your classpath or within your JAR file.

You don't include you package names so I cannot provide a more direct example to help solve your problem.

Comment: All of them are under a src folder. so in the root, I add a META-INF/services/ folder?

Comment: Correct. The `ServiceLoader` is looking for them in this folder (`META-INF/services/`) starting at your source folder, e.g. srcFolder/META-INF/services/xxx.yyy.zzz.DBDriver. It cannot second guess you.